# cannot read edittext input on spinner

Tags: android

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myDialog = new Dialog(this);
    weight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    btn_result = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    /*SPINER*/
    Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.names));
    myAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    mySpinner.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            double x = Double.parseDouble(weight.getText().toString());
            switch (i) {
                case 1:
                    if (x <= 0.5) {
                        totalPrice = 5;
                        Price= totalPrice * 20 / 100;
                        Fee = totalPrice * 80 / 100;
                    } else {
                        totalPrice2 = x * 9;
                        Price= totalPrice * 20 / 100;
                        Fee = totalPrice * 80 / 100;
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "You selected case1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    if (x <= 0.5) {
                        totalPrice2 = 7;
                        Price= totalPrice * 20 / 100;
                        Fee = totalPrice * 80 / 100;
                    } else {
                        totalPrice = x * 12.90;
                        Price= totalPrice * 20 / 100;
                        Fee = totalPrice * 80 / 100;
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "You selected case2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break
                }
            }
        });
    }

    //here the problem cannot read the editText input 

    /*07-04 07:55:58.893 4268-4268/com.wedee.testalgo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.wedee.testalgo, PID: 4268
java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
    at java.lang.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1071)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:547)
    at com.wedee.testalgo.MainActivity$1.onItemSelected(MainActivity.java:44)
    at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:1319)
    at android.widget.AdapterView.dispatchOnItemSelected(AdapterView.java:1308)
    at android.widget.AdapterView.-wrap1(AdapterView.java)
    at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:1275)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6823)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1563)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1451)*/
```

the input value from the edittext cannot get the inputted value from the edittext to the spinner can any1 give some suggestion how to get it.... 
double x = Double.parseDouble(weight.getText().toString()); i get an error from this line 
is there any method should i do to get the input....

Answer (score 1):

As the error says `java.lang.NumberFormatException: **empty String**`

You need to enter some `double` value in your `EditText` (weight), before selecting anything from your spinner.

Comment: Before that, you need to enter data in the EditText. Then try to read using `double weight1 = Double.parsedouble(weight.getText().tostring());`

Comment: already done it it show an error on my edittext layout....

Comment: @redja what error do you see in layout?

Comment: when i put double on weight show an error here 'weight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);'

Comment: @redja are you getting `empty String` error?

Comment: no its say incompatible type and i already put inputtype as numberdecimal on xml

Comment: @redja try `weight.getText().trim().toString()` to avoid spaces. What is the input that you are providing?

Comment: float n int.....

Comment: @redja then `double x =Double.parseDouble(weight.getText().toString());` should not give error, the incompitable type must me somewhere else. check whether type for `totalPrice` , `Price`, `Fee` is double

Comment: yeah i think that also should didnt give an error the totalPrice, Price and Fee is already a double and when i run the code apps crash and the problem is a double x.

Answer (score 0):

As the stack trace states, there is an empty string: `" "` in the `EditText` which cannot be converted to a `Double`.

The two ways to solve this could be adding an if statement to check for this condition or by adding an attribute to your EditText XML: `android:inputType` which you can configure to only recieve floating point numbers from the EditText (`inputDecimal`).

See the first part of this Android Documentation for all the input types: 
https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style